# C-Passing arguments for execution of a program in new Xterm window

Tags: c, linux, parameter-passing, xterm

**Problem statement:-**

How to pass arguments to a program for execution in a new Xterm/Gnome window which will be calling through execlp.

**A little elaborate explanation:-**(oxymoron eh?)

Consider the following program which will take a string as argument and display it

```
//output.c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc<2)
        {
              printf("insufficient parameters\n");
              exit(1);
        }
    printf("%s",argv[1]);
    sleep(10);
    return 0;
```

}

And another program,`client.c`which, during the course of its execution is required to call `output.c` and make it display in a new xterm/gnome-terminal window.

```
//client.c
int main()
{
    char buf[25]="Test String";//as argument for program to be called
    int pid_child=fork();
    if(pid_child==-1)
            {
                printf("Fork Failed. Exiting");
                exit(1);
            }

    if(pid_child==0)
            {   
            execlp("/usr/bin/xterm","-e","./output",buf,NULL);
            }

    int status=0;
    while(wait(&status)!=-1);
}
```

The line of contention here is

```
execlp("/usr/bin/xterm","-e","./output",buf,NULL); //With string `buf` as argument for `output`.
```

Result:-Does not run

> Error
>   -e: Explicit shell already was /~/cs60/directory/./output
>
> -e: bad command line option "Test String"

```
execlp("/usr/bin/xterm","-e","./output",NULL);//Without passing variable `buf`
```

Result:-  a)  New Xterm window opens.   b) output terminates with Insufficient parameters (as expected).

The manpage clearly states for Xterm:

> > -e program [ arguments ... ]
>
> ```
>             This option specifies the program (and its command  line  arguments) to be run in the xterm window.
> ```

It works perfectly fine when I run it from a terminal (as a script). But how can I achieve this through C.

Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand how [`execlp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execlp.html) works.

You need to add a second argument to `execlp` with the command name ("xterm").

```
execlp("/usr/bin/xterm", "xterm", "-e", "./output", buf, NULL);
```

Also, your output program may want to do a `fflush` (so you see the output), and you should exit or otherwise take proper evasive action if `execl()` fails.  Note that when the command name (`"/usr/bin/xterm"`) contains any slashes, `execlp()` behaves the same as `execl()`.

Comment: Yeah, Guess my understanding of execlp did infact yeild this. But not the ignorance of not consulting the manual. Thanks anyways